# Django sql query with None in field of WHERE clause not working

Tags: sql, django

I am having issues when writing sql query for django.

If the query is `Books.objects.filter(id=1, name='ABC')`, the sql query using django.db.connection would be:

```
cur = connection.cursor()
cur.execute('SELECT title FROM book WHERE id = %s AND name = %s',[id, name])
```

This works if there is a value in the name field but returns [] if name is None.  So what should the equivalent be for `Books.objects.filter(id=1, name=None)`.

What would be the query to accommodate both None and other values?

```
cur = connection.cursor()
for id, name in [(1, 'A'),(2, None),(3, 'TEST')]:
    cur.execute('????',[id, name])
```

I was wondering if there would be a query that could be used in place of `'????'` in the above code.

Comment: I think `Books.objects.filter(id=1, name=None)` should be written `Books.objects.filter(id=1, name__isnull=True)`

Comment: But what would that look like if it were to be in `cur.execute('SELECT title FROM book WHERE `...

Comment: SELECT column_names
FROM table_name
WHERE column_name IS NULL;

Comment: As the last example code, if I have a mix of both, i will need to separate [(1, 'A'),(2, None),(3, 'TEST')] to [(1, 'A'),(3, 'TEST')] and [(2, None)] and use  `SELECT title FROM book WHERE id = %s AND name = %s` and `SELECT title FROM book WHERE id = %s and name IS NULL`?

Comment: @1010101: Django takes `None` into account, and will replace the `name = ...` with `name IS NULL` given that parameter is `None`.

Comment: Yes Django does it. I was wondering if there is a query that can be used to fill the '????' in the code.

Comment: @1010101: no, as far as I know you can not use `=` here. There was some extra logic to do the replacement if I recall correctly in the Django ORM.

Comment: @1010101: I however do not really understand why you aim to write the queries manually however?

Comment: As I was not able to do Django query for bulk querying of the form `(id, name) in [(id1, name1), (id2, name2), (id3, name3)]` whereas using execute I could do `WHERE id=%s AND name=%s OR id=%s AND name=%s`

Comment: @1010101: you can make a bulk query, and there is in fact a way to circumvent the `IS NULL` conversion, although I strongly advise against it. See updated answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What would be the query to accommodate both None and other values.

Django actually accommodates both `None` and other values. If we look at the query that is generated, it will look like:

```
>>> print(Book.objects.filter(id=4, name=None).query)
SELECT `app_book`.`id`, `app_book`.`name` FROM `app_book` WHERE (`app_book`.`id` = 4 AND `app_book`.`name` IS NULL)
```

If you thus pass `None` in the filter, then it will translate this to `IS NULL`.

and for a specific string:

```
>>> print(Book.objects.filter(id=4, name='Book name').query)
SELECT `app_book`.`id`, `app_book`.`name` FROM `app_book` WHERE (`app_book`.`id` = 4 AND `app_book`.`name` = Book name)
```

You can make it more explicit by using the [**`__isnull`** lookup [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#isnull):

```
Book.objects.filter(id=4, name__isnull=True)
```

In SQL, you can *not* check with `NULL` by writing `=`, since:

```
mysql> select NULL = NULL, NULL is NULL, 'foo' is NULL, 'foo' = NULL;
+-------------+--------------+---------------+--------------+
| NULL = NULL | NULL is NULL | 'foo' is NULL | 'foo' = NULL |
+-------------+--------------+---------------+--------------+
|        NULL |            1 |             0 |         NULL |
+-------------+--------------+---------------+--------------+
```

Indeed, checks with `NULL` result in `NULL` as well.

> I was wondering if there would be a query that could be used in place of '????' in the above code

You could make a more sophisticated check, like:

```
cur.execute(
    'SELECT title FROM book WHERE id = %s AND (name = %s or (name = %s) is NULL)',
    [id, name, name]
)
```

But this makes it more complex and harder to read, and probably it will make the query slower than formatting it properly.

If you want to select all values that satisfy a 2-tuple, you could generate a query like:

```
from django.db.models import Q
from functools import reduce
from operator import or_

data = [(1, 'A'),(2, None),(3, 'TEST')]

Book.objects.filter(
    reduce(or_, [Q(id=id, name=name) for id, name in data])
)
```